# Submit Two forms in one controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

How can I make sure that, that second form elements go to the database cause when I check there the is no data but its been inputted by the user, if both forms are called from one controller

```
$form = new Form_Form1(); 
$this->view->form = $form;

$form2 = new Form_Form2();  
$this->view->form2 = $form2;


if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($form->isValid($formData) && $form2->isValid($formData)) {...
```